# Update and insert in a bulk move (SQL Server)

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a pair of databases, one is a live database and one is for testing a configuration for that live database. Both reside on the same server.

I have three tables, Users (PK UserId, FK MainGroupId) and Groups (PK GroupId) and GroupMembers (PK GroupMemberId, FK GroupId and UserId).

The tables are the same schema on both databases however the test database has a set of special test users. Groups is mostly stable, but sometimes we add groups, and sometimes we change column data in the groups. GroupMembers is the same but in the test database refers to the test users.

I need to be able to update the Groups table from the live to test user programmatically. I want to use a bulk copy operation, but to do so I have to delete the Groups table first, which will cause a constraint violation.

I could copy the table in bulk to a dummy table, and then post process by doing an insert of the new rows, and update on the existing rows. However, my problems is that there are about 30 tables like Groups, and I don't want to encode all the column names into the stored procedure in the UPDATE SET method. I'd also like to be able to do it in bulk.

The DBAs are dubious about granting ALTER TABLE permission to temporarily drop the constraints.

Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SInce both databases are on the same server, why not use a MERGE statement?

Comment: That would be because I've never heard of a merge statement! Thanks for educating me, it was a big help.

Answer (score 0):

select for export and import. If you do it in the right order it should work correctly.